# Real numbers in Go

Tags: go, math

How to work with real numbers in Go?

For instance:

```
(627.71/640.26)^(1/30) = 0.999340349 --> correct result
```

but with Go:

```
fmt.Print(math.Pow((627.71 / 640.26), (1 / 30))) = 1 --> wrong
```

Comment: To trouble-shoot something like this you could look at each part of you calculation and see if it gives you the expected result, quickly you would come to `1 / 30` giving you zero.

Comment: Note that the best approximation to a real number (for whatever reals you like) in Go are mathh/big.Float and the next less accurate are float64s which you used. But _never_ think of them as reals!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use floating-point (real), not integer, division. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Print(math.Pow((627.71 / 640.26), (1.0 / 30.0)))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/o7uVw9doaMu

Output:

```
0.999340348749526
```

---

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(1 / 30)     // integer division
    fmt.Println(1.0 / 30.0) // floating-point division
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/VW9vilCC9M8

Output:

```
0
0.03333333333333333
```

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Integer literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_literals)
>
> [Floating-point literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Floating-point_literals)
>
> [Arithmetic operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators)
>
> Integer operators
>
> For two integer values x and y, the integer quotient q = x / y and
>   remainder r = x % y satisfy the following relationships:
>
> ```
> x = q*y + r  and  |r| < |y|
> ```
>
> with x / y truncated towards zero ("truncated division").